# How should I start playing and running Role-playing games

Tags: new-players, new-gm

I want to start playing Role-playing games, so how should I start playing and running Role-playing games? 
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. We've got a question about starting with role-playing games already, so I've marked this as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: If you find the linked Q&A unsatisfactory, once you have 20 reputation you can always hop into [chat] and talk to people there :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D I didn't know how to start on this.